# Error in angularui boostrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I have a datePicker when required clause true  and its initial value is today. When I leave blank I got this error :+1: 
Error: I is undefined q@http://localhost/SafeTravelClient/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.min.js:8:6100 this.init/<@http://localhost/SafeTravelClient/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.min.js:8:9508

I guess it would try to apply some formatting or something and find a null value...

Any hint...

Comment: are you reading that value? please add more info, add your html code, and your function

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This is my html code

> ```
>                 <div class="row">
>                     <div class="col-xs-3">
>                         <label class="control-label">Desde</label>
>                         <p class="input-group">
>                             <input type="text" 
>                                    class="form-control" 
>                                    uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" 
>                                    ng-model="dpDesde" 
>                                    ng-change='dpDesde_Change()'
>                                    is-open="popup1.opened" 
>                                    ng-required="true" 
>                                    close-text='Cerrar'
>                                    clear-text='Limpiar'
>                                    current-text='Hoy'
>                                    datepicker-options="dateOptions"
>                                    alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
>                             <span class="input-group-btn">
>                                 <button type="button" 
>                                         class="btn btn-default" 
>                                         ng-click="openDatePop(1)">
>                                     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
>                             </span>
>                         </p>
>                     </div>
> ```